# systemd service run before and after other service starts

Tags: linux, service, systemd

I want to run a script before and after autofs starts.
I have two systemd service:

backup1.service runs before autofs

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/backup/sw/bmount before


[Install]
WantedBy=autofs.service
```

backup2.service runs after autofs

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup mount
PartOf=autofs.service
After=autofs.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/backup/sw/bmount after

[Install]
WantedBy=autofs.service
```

I can determine the after/before status in the bmount script, so I can call it without parameter and I could use only one service, but don't know how.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this:

## Edit autofs.service

By design, service files should be site-maintainable.  On Debian-based platforms, vendor-supplied service files are in `/lib/systemd/system/`, I think redhat has them in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` but you can override these with site-managed service files in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

In that case, I'd

```
cp /lib/systemd/system/autofs.service /etc/systemd/system/autofs.service
```

Then in the `[Service]` section, I'd add:

```
ExecStartPre=/backup/sw/bmount before
ExecStartPost=/backup/sw/bmount after
```

The `systemd.service` manpage says:

> ExecStart= commands are only run after all ExecStartPre= commands exit successfully.
>
> ExecStartPost= commands are only run after the commands specified in ExecStart= have been invoked successfully, as determined by Type= (i.e. the process has been started for Type=simple or Type=idle, the last ExecStart= process exited successfully for Type=oneshot, ...).

## Drop-in service parameters

A more elegant way to do the same thing as what's above is to use a drop-in.  Simply create `/etc/systemd/system/autofs.service.d/backup.conf` with this content:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPre=/backup/sw/bmount before
ExecStartPost=/backup/sw/bmount after
```

## Relationships

Maybe `autofs.service` already has `ExecStartPre` and `ExecStartPost` commands and you are worried about interferring with that service.  In that case, you can use relationships to start/stop your services.

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup mount
PartOf=autofs.service
Before=autofs.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/backup/sw/bmount before

[Install]
WantedBy=autofs.service
```

and

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup mount
PartOf=autofs.service
After=autofs.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/backup/sw/bmount after

[Install]
WantedBy=autofs.service
```

In this case:

- `PartOf=autofs.service` means "When systemd stops or restarts `autofs.service`, the action is propagated to `backup.service`"
- `Before=autofs.service` means "If both units are being started, `autofs.service`'s startup is delayed until `backup.service` has finished starting up."
- `After=autofs.service` means "If both units are being started, `backup.service`'s startup is delayed until `autofs.service` has finished starting up."
- `WantedBy=autofs.service` means "`backup.service` will be started if `autofs.service` is".
- `Type=oneshot` means that the service will still be considered as running, even after the `ExecStart=` process completes.

Be sure to run `systemctl daemon-reload` so systemd reads the new service.  Also run `systemctl enable backup.service` to ensure that the `WantedBy=` becomes a `Wants=` for `autofs.service`.

I think you were pretty close with your solution.

Comment: I think modifying the autofs service is not the way to go, but the Drop-in service parameters method works well. Thank you!

Comment: That's very true.  You don't want to modify the original service file, partially because any changes made by the package maintainers will not be applied to your device.  Another trick:  You can use `systemctl edit autofs.service` to create the file in the drop-in directory.